# How to cast a Hashmap to Map

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, collections, hashmap

i want to cast a hashmap :

my code:

```
public class Example {

private HashMap<MyItem, Integer> items =new HashMap<MyItem, Integer>();


@Override
public Map<Item, Integer> gItems() {
    return this.items;
}

}
```

MyItem is a class who inherit from Item class.

this code give me a compilation error.

For manay reason i can't use the solution  to change the type of the return method.

**So how can i cast my** `HashMap<MyItem, Integer>`  **TO a** `Map<Item, Integer>`

**The error i'm getting is:**
Type mismatch:cannot convert from `HashMap<MyItem, Integer>` to `Map<Item, Integer>`

and the compilator ask me to change the type of return method.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: Google "why aren't generics covariant?"

Comment: Problem is not `HashMap -> Map`, but `<MyItem> -> <Item>`. What is the relation between them? Maybe you could use bounded wildcards

Comment: i said MyItem inherit from Item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to cast because `Map<MyItem, Integer>` is not a subtype of `Map<Item, Integer>`. This is described in details in the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) (see the section Generics and Subtyping).

What you can do in this case is have your function return a `Map<? extends Item, Integer>`

Comment: thank you , the problem i'm deeling is that when i do a put operation to the collection , it is added even if it is already in the hashmap.for that i'm trying to use a MyItem as a key in the hashmap.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. What other problem are you having? You can keep the declaration of the map the same, just change the return type of the function

Comment: anyway thank you , i think in my case it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

edit: See testinfected's answer, it's right/makes more sense.

There's probably a problem higher in your stack if code that's calling yours can't handle a type implementing a desired interface, but you can cast like so:

```
return (Map)this.items;
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. He doesn't need to cast an inheriting class. The issue is that the return type is of Map<Item, Integer> and the instance type is of HashMap<MyItem, Integer>. Note that one uses "Item" as a key and one uses "MyItem" as a key.